# different flavors in android

Tags: android, gradle, build

I want to create smth like this in my project, but i'm new to gradle, so i don't know a lot of things it can do.

[image]

Here is project structure in explorer
[image]

gradle.build from app module

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.7'
    }
}

// Manifest version information!
def versionMajor = 1
def versionMinor = 0
def versionPatch = 0
def versionBuild = 0 // bump for dogfood builds, public betas, etc.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

def gitSha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
def date = new Date()
def buildTime = date.format("dd.MM.yy", TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
def buildTimeInternal = date.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'", TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion

        versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 1000 + versionPatch * 100 + versionBuild
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"

        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_SHA", "\"${gitSha}\""
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${buildTimeInternal}\""

        testApplicationId "ru.ltst.u2020mvp.tests"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("../distribution/debug.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }
        release {
            storeFile file("../distribution/debug.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
            versionNameSuffix '-dev'
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), file('proguard-project.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        internal {
            applicationId 'ru.ltst.u2020mvp.internal'
        }
        production {
            applicationId 'ru.ltst.u2020mvp'
        }
    }


    lintOptions {
        textReport true
        textOutput 'stdout'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

// TODO remove eventually: http://b.android.com/162285
configurations {
    internalDebugCompile
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    internalDebugCompile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit-mock:1.9.0'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.7.1'
    internalDebugCompile 'com.jakewharton.madge:madge:1.1.1'
    internalDebugCompile 'com.jakewharton.scalpel:scalpel:1.1.1'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.8'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'

    internalCompile 'com.mattprecious.telescope:telescope:1.4.0@aar'

    // Espresso 2 Dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
}

// change apk name
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    for (output in variant.outputs) {
        def outputFile = output.outputFile
        if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
            def fileName = "u2020-mvp-${output.name}-${buildTime}.apk"
            output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
        }
    }
}

// print build finish time
gradle.buildFinished { buildResult ->
    def buildFinishDate = new Date()
    def formattedDate = buildFinishDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
    println "Build finished: ${formattedDate}"
}
```

Can someone explain to me how it works?

When i change build Variant the java content is changed. (e.g it was main, internal,internalDebug for internalDebug variant and then it became main,internal,internalRelease for internalRelease build variants).

The reason I'm asking is that i don't see any "internalRelease" word in gradle file, so i don't understand the logic of how the build variants were created and how it defines what modules to show for different build variants

Answer (score 1):

debug for test without signature and release for publish with signature;click the left-top robot ,and turn android to project , u will understand;

Comment: ye, i know the difference between debug and release but how this internalDebug, productionDebug is connected to gradle file.

Comment: productFlavors  + buildTypes   simplely.productFlavors {
        internal {
        }
        production {
 
        }
    }buildTypes   {debug {} release{}}